# seg fault 11, object pointer, ADT implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, object, fault

**PROBLEM**

not understanding what logical error is occuring. 

trying to call the function clear_queue() in my main.cpp test

**MY GUESS occurs in while loop at the last object to be dequeued but im not sure what  really is happening, I THINK ITS BECAUSE IT TRIES TO DEQUEUE ONE TOO MANY**

**my `Queue` class variables**

   - beginning (pointer to node class object)

   - end (pointer to node class object)

   - count (int)


**`Node` class**

-constructor has one param (int data)

-next (pointer)

-value (int)


**`enqueue()`**

enque implemented 

makes new node object , update queue pointers, store data, increment count
with one param "data" stores in `beginning->value`

**`dequeue & clear_queue()`**

//needs to return the dequeued value

queue.cpp

```
    int Queue::dequeue() {

            if (! isEmpty()) {

            Node *temp = beginning;
            int tempValue = temp->value;

            temp->value = tempValue;
            beginning = beginning->next;

            delete temp;
            count --;
            return tempValue;
        }

}
```

queue_test.cpp

```
void QueueTest::clear_queue() {
  test_header( "clearing the queue (isEmpty and dequeue)" );

  while( ! queue->isEmpty() ) {
    queue->dequeue();
  }
```

//test message outputs message, should output "pass" if the subroutine successfully finished. 

//test header just output message

//getting seg fault: 11

output

```
--- Testing clearing the queue (isEmpty and dequeue) ---

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault: 11; real time: 290ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: No howlers jump out in the provided code. Are you certain `isEmpty` works? Are you certain nothing you did before calling `clear_queue` damages the links? Have you taken a  stroll through the links with the debugger?

Comment: no i havent that sounds like a great idea. isEmpty is a bool function that returns end==Null

Comment: FIXED isEmpty changed to return count==0;

Comment: I recommend also looking into why end was not the expected NULL. Could be another lurking bug ready to strike.

Comment: yeah no i changed it to compare count and 0 because end just never will get set to null